# Magento 2 URL Redirect (301) not working

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

I am trying to redirect account creation to account sign in.  I create customer accounts in admin panel instead.  However attempting to redirect using Magento's URL Rewrite module is not working for me.

- URL Rewrite: Custom
- Store: Default store view
- Request path: `customer/account/create`
- Target path: `customer/account/login`
- Redirect Type: Permanent(301)

Upon clicking "create account" in the store, it doesn't redirect to sign in page.

I am using Google Chrome and also tried with Safari.  I have cleared my browser cache, reindexed and cached Magento but to no avail.

Here's a photo of my configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is no longer possible in Magento to overwrite controller routes with url rewrites. In routers list sort order for `Magento\Framework\App\Router\Base` is 10 and for `Magento\UrlRewrite\Controller\Router` sort order is 40.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to redirect using Magento Admin Panel but instead, I included this line in .htaccess in root magento directory:

RewriteRule customer/account/create http://example.com/customer/account/login [L,R=301].